# Modal not showing up in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am rendering this component from the main component. I am facing issues with Modal in react-bootstrap. My modal is not showing up properly. i have attached the screenshot of how my modal looks. Please if anyone could help?

This is how my model shows up
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvnmU.png

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';

class Add_Recipe extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            showAdd: false
        };
    }
  handleAddRecipe(e){
      this.setState({showAdd: true});
  }

close() {
    this.setState({ showAdd: false });
  }

render() { 

      return(
          <div className="Add_Recipe">

            <Button onClick ={this.handleAddRecipe.bind(this)} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large"> Add Recipe </Button>
                <Modal show={this.state.showAdd} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="modalTitle">Add a Recipe</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <p>
             Hello i am Modal..!!
            </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <p>
               Hello I am Footer
            </p>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
          </div>
      );
}

}
export default Add_Recipe;
```

This is my index.html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">     
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.

    -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Error ? Try to bind the function in the constructor instead of doing it in render

Comment: Please have a look at the image i have posted.

Comment: Did you includes bootstrap css in your app ?  Also you can update import to `import {Modal, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'`

Comment: I have included my index.html and index.js files please have a look. Please walk me through complete process of installation of react-bootstrap.